# Visual studio mac Automatic Provisioning failed: An App ID with Identifier 'aaa.bbb.ccc' is not available. Please enter a different string

Tags: xamarin.ios, maui, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to upgrade my iOS native application to Mac Catalyst. Had to make platforms folder with iOS and Catalyst folders and in proj file I specify that it usesmaui 'true'.
When I choose automatic provisioning for my iOS app everything is fine. (you can now deploy your app), but when I choose automatic provisioning for Catalyst app it says that app identifier is already used. Which is off course true, but it must be the same as my iOS app.
The app is already in the app store for several years.

```
Resolving certificate...
Syncing certificates for "John Doe" team...
Saving Apple Development certificates...
Fetching locally installed signing identities...
Syncing App IDs for "John Doe" team...
Trying to find App ID matching aaa.bbb.ccc...
Your application is using entitlements not supported by wildcard App IDs...
    * com.apple.developer.applesignin
Creating a new App ID based on specific Bundle ID...
Creating new App ID: VS aaa bbb ccc (aaa.bbb.ccc)...

Automatic Provisioning failed: An App ID with Identifier 'aaa.bbb.ccc' is not available. Please enter a different string.
```

When I enter different name it says another error:

```
Resolving certificate...
Syncing certificates for "John Doe" team...
Saving Apple Development certificates...
Fetching locally installed signing identities...
Syncing App IDs for "John Dow" team...
Trying to find App ID matching aaa.bbb.ccc.justtest...
Your application is using entitlements not supported by wildcard App IDs...
    * com.apple.developer.applesignin
Creating a new App ID based on specific Bundle ID...
Creating new App ID: VS aaa bbb ccc justtest (aaa.bbb.ccc.justtest)...
Saving new App ID...
Updating VS aaa bbb ccc justtest entitlements...
Making sure that connected devices are registered in "John Doe" team...
Syncing devices for "John Doe" team...
Processing mac devices...
Syncing provisioning profiles for "John Doe" team...
Saving profiles...
Syncing devices for "John Doe" team...
Processing mac devices...

Automatic Provisioning failed: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
```

When I use Manual Provisioning, there is no Provisioning profile in the dropdown list. I've tried different ways to populate them, but had no luck.

Comment: The error indicates that there's no matched An App ID with Identifier with your Mac Catalyst app. You may need manually regenerating prov profiles, please go through:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/mac-catalyst/capabilities

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT as a developer I can say that you do not handle errors properly, value cannot be null does not explain me what to do. It is an internal error, which I should not see. I spend several days trying to regenerate provisioning profiles manually without any success. It works in xcode with the same app id, it took me 10 minutes to make it work.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT first error I posted above is a MS mistake. It should not create new Id, since it already exist.